# Convert Minutes to Clock Time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert minutes into clock time.

I have e.g. minutes = 27822 and want to convert that into clock time even if it passes 24:00 i.e 27822 Minutes = 52:45. I have tried:

```
CAST([Down Time Minutes] AS DECIMAL(38, 8)) / 3600
```

This only gives me the hours i.e 03:50 and not with days included if it goes past 24 hours

Comment: hint: use the modulus operator `%` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/modulo-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: The `time` datatype can't store a value greater than `23:59:59.9999999`. If you do need to store values greater than 24 hours for a time, I personally suggest to stick to using the interval value you have in your database and using your presentation layer to change the value. Otherwise you have to use a `varchar`, and that is likely unadvisable (`11:00` is not "lower" that `2:00`, but `'11:00'` **is** lower than `'02:00'`). In Excel/SSRS for example, you can use the **display** format `[hh]:mm` to display a datetime in hours &minutes (I.e `1900-01-02T17:00:00` would be displayed as `41:00`).

Comment: In C# you can use [TimeSpan.FromMinutes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromminutes?view=netframework-4.8) to make the conversion you want. Is there a reason you want to make this conversion in the database>

Comment: What does `52:45` have to do with `27822`?  The first is 3,165 minutes.  The second would be `463:42`.

Answer (score 0):

Please, please, please read the comments that Larnu and Gordon Linoff left - there are very good points and questions in there that should be considered, particularly about how you're choosing to store your data vs how you present it.

But, since it seemed like a fun warm-up with my coffee and I always need a reason to go check on my 2005 installation, here are some options for converting your `INT` to something that looks sort of like clock time. All of these will output 463:42 as Gordon pointed out.

```
DECLARE @t INT;
SET @t = 20;

/*SQL Server pre-2008*/
SELECT LEFT('00',2-LEN(@t/60))+CAST((@t/60) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':' + LEFT('00',2-LEN(@t%60))+CAST((@t%60) AS VARCHAR(2)) 

/*SQL Server 2008+ -- longer, but we get to play with REPLICATE*/
SELECT  REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(@t/60))+CAST((@t/60) AS VARCHAR(5)) + ':' + REPLICATE('0',2-LEN(@t%60))+CAST((@t%60) AS VARCHAR(2))

/*SQL Server 2012+*/
SELECT CONCAT(FORMAT((@t/60),'0#'),':',FORMAT((@t%60),'0#'))
```